# Does it make sense to restrict the usage of Metasploit in Penetration testing exams ?

Tags: exploit, metasploit

In some PT exams (mainly [Offensive Security](https://www.offensive-security.com/)'s) they restrict the usage of Metasploit or any automated attacking tool and allow only for manually written\compiled codes from public exploit sites such as [exploit-db](https://www.exploit-db.com/).

Taking into account that many exploits are either too complicated for an [OSCP's](https://www.offensive-security.com/information-security-certifications/oscp-offensive-security-certified-professional/) student to understand (such as kernel exploits )  and most of them requires some fixing before they work.

So is there a valid reasons behind that ?

Prohibiting automated vulnerabilities scanners makes sense to me (or at least i can understand the reason behind it ) 
But can't say the same on preventing the use of Metasploit for exploitation (students are allowed to use MSF handlers and payload generators )

Comment: "many exploits are either too complicated for an OSCP's student to understand" I think you need to re-evaluate that statement.

Comment: *"So is there a valid reasons behind that?"* Yes, don't be a tool-monkey and know what are you really doing.

Answer (score 7):

A test is free to restrict the conditions of a test for their own reasons depending on the *effect* that they want to test.

Remember that the point is not to "get the right answer" but to teach and test ***understanding*** of the underlying concepts. It's like restricting the use of calculators when the test is about testing the student's ability to calculate based on their wits alone.

So, it is certainly valid to restrict the use of certain tools if your goal is to graduate someone who can understand how to modify and use exploits from exploit-db (even kernel ones) with confidence.